# coalesce with a condition?

Tags: sql

I think I need help with a query, I'm probably overcomplicating things mentally, but how would I change this date_add

```
DATE_ADD(ceorder.orderdate_dt,INTERVAL profile.maxexpiration_i DAY) as maxExpirationDate
to use

course.override_expiration_days_i
```

if not null, instead of

```
profile.maxexpiration_i
```

but only if the variable

```
course.producttype_vc
```

equals 'Electronic Book' so kind of like a coalesce but with an extra condition?

the entire query for context

```
 private String SELECT_EXTENSION = "select ceordereditem.expiration_dt as currentExpirationDate, DATE_ADD(ceorder.orderdate_dt,INTERVAL profile.maxexpiration_i DAY) as maxExpirationDate, coursedetail.price_f as itemPrice, ceordereditem.approvalnumber_vc as approvalNumber, extension_percent_b as percentage, extension_price_f as extensionPrice, extension_interval_days_i as extensionDays " +
     "from coursedetail, ceordereditem, ceorder, profile " +
     "where ceordereditem.ceorder_id_i = ceorder.id_i and coursedetail.profile_id_i = profile.id_i and ceordereditem.coursedetail_id_i = coursedetail.id_i and ceordereditem.id_i = ?";
```

Comment: What you posted looks like a string in a programming language like Java or C# to me. are you talking about a particular so-called `RDBMS` like for example PostgreSQL? Do you want to Tag your Question accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

coalesce is just a shortcut for a `case|when` block. If you want to do something more complex than just returning a fallback value when null, you can use a case expression. Example:

```
CASE  
WHEN (yourDataField IS NOT NULL) THEN yourDataField
WHEN (yourDataField IS NULL AND course.producttype_vc = "Electronic Book") THEN course.override_expiration_days_i
ELSE somethingElseHere
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE WHEN THEN END in T-sql, like:

```
select ceordereditem.expiration_dt as currentExpirationDate, CASE WHEN course.override_expiration_days_i IS NOT NULL AND course.producttype_vc = 'Electronic Book' 
THEN DATE_ADD(ceorder.orderdate_dt,INTERVAL course.override_expiration_days_i DAY) 
ELSE DATE_ADD(ceorder.orderdate_dt,INTERVAL profile.maxexpiration_i DAY) END as maxExpirationDate, coursedetail.price_f as itemPrice, ceordereditem.approvalnumber_vc as approvalNumber, extension_percent_b as percentage, extension_price_f as extensionPrice, extension_interval_days_i as extensionDays " +
     "from coursedetail, ceordereditem, ceorder, profile " +
     "where ceordereditem.ceorder_id_i = ceorder.id_i and coursedetail.profile_id_i = profile.id_i and ceordereditem.coursedetail_id_i = coursedetail.id_i and ceordereditem.id_i = ?
```